# Incorrect days to open to public on Programmers/Not Programming Related

Tags: bug, status-completed, private-beta

A friend of mine tried to visit [Not Programming Related](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and saw this:

[image: 0 Days to Public]

It clearly says that the site will be open to the public in 0 days. However, the site just went into private beta. It should say that the site will be open to the public in 7 days.

Comment: +1 for lo-tech cell-phone snapshot of screen.  Your cell phone is not capable of freehand circles, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

this was fixed an hour or so ago. has to do with static variables in multiple instancing.

Comment: OK. I'll let him know. I can't see that page since I'm part of the beta, and he's not physically near me. Thanks, Jeff.

Comment: @Thomas Looks good from here (I'm not in the beta)